# Silverlight/WPF vs Flash : supposed to be similar according to Microsoft but not really

Tags: wpf, silverlight, flash, actionscript-3

Microsoft has promoted Silverlight as alternative to Flash with similar scripting. But while being a novice on both in Flash I could easily attach an event handler to a shape, in Silverlight it's stunningly difficult ! I cannot even capture a mouse event click on a shape:

[Why OnMouseDown handler exists but is not called for an ellipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781942/why-onmousedown-handler-exists-but-is-not-called-for-an-ellipse)

So is there any other difficulties like this in wpf/silverlight ?

I'm studying both to know which one to choose. I have always worked with MS until now. So I would prefer to continue with MS but I'm afraid Silverlight/WPF are overcomplicated compared to Flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight is NOT similar to Flash.  It is, however, similar to Flex, which is an SDK that runs in the Flash/Air runtimes. So, in that regard, they are similar.  If you want to compare, you need to compare with Flex.

Here is a series of posts (written by me) comparing Silverlight and Flex feature by feature.  They are strikingly similar:

http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2010/10/24/cross-training-in-silverlight-vs-flex/

Comment: Good remarks am reading http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2010/11/08/cross-training-in-silverlight-and-flex-xaml-vs-mxml/

Comment: Don't fear the perf.  Try it.  Do some tests.  I have never run into perf issues in Flex.  That doesn't mean they aren't there, but that the ceiling is high enough that a reasonably complex app in Flex performs as well as the same app in Silverlight.  If you need to start rocking your graphics, then Flex isn't your platform.  The majority of the UI layer in Silverlight, for that matter, isn't for graphic intensive coding either.

Comment: is it just talk, or is MS really pushing Silverlight towards being the primary development platform for WP7?

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978: It is not just talk... Silverlight IS the primary development platform in Windows Phone 7 (WP7).  Right now, your options are Silverlight or XNA.  XNA is for games/graphics and is very different from Silverlight.  But this is Silverlight on the device, not Silverlight in the browser.  Very much like Air as a development platform for Android, Silverlight is a VERY nice framework for developing mobile apps.  The only difference is that Silverlight is built into the OS where Air in Android is a boot-strapped layer.

Answer (score 1):

The handler for an Ellipse (in Silverlight) would be called MouseLeftButtonDown and it works just fine for me on an Ellipse so I'm guessing that you're doing something more than you're saying here?

Mike.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be related to [routed events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189018%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#routed_events).

Comment: Well thanks but no it's due to the fact that I had to add a fill property which is silly as it is another concept than event.

Comment: All platforms have their quirks.  Thankfully this one is minor.